# managing a hierarchy of docker images

Tags: docker

I'm thinking of the following use case:

1. base image with ubuntu server
2. image with java7 setup, child of the first
3. image with a java application, say spring based, that uses the 2nd as parent

Now, say for example that I want to add to all images extending the first some monitoring capabilities, and as a consequence I modify the first.

Is there a way, a tool maybe, that will trigger the auto build, in my local environment, of all children once the build of the base image completes?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use a small tool called [docker-bakery](https://github.com/smartrecruiters/docker-bakery) that analyses structure of `dockerfiles` and enables triggering hierarchical builds when parent image changes.

For example when `dog` image changes the child images can be automatically rebuild.

```
├── alpine-java
│   ├── bird
│   └── mammal
│       ├── cat
│       ├── dog
│       │   ├── dobermann
│       │   │   └── smaller-dobermann
│       │   ├── pitbull
│       │   └── labrador
│       └── horse
└── scratch
    └── fish
```

The invocation in case of `dog` rebuild could as simple as:

```
$/docker-bakery-example> cd dog
$/dog> make build-major-all
...
// docker build of child images
... 
$/dog> make push-major-all
```

Here is an [example project](https://github.com/smartrecruiters/docker-bakery-example) with `dockerfiles` and `make` files that make the usage very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

I our organization, we have a git repo with all our base images (this includes 1 and 2 in your list) ie the Dockerfiles. Application specific images are left to the individual teams and their repos (3 in your list)

We just have a simple shell script that builds and publishes each of these images in order. Each checkin to this images repo will trigger a build in our CI system (http://www.go.cd/) and hence ends up building all the images again.

Simple setup, but with around 10 base images, and around 3 levels of depth, this works well for us.

Comment: thx for the perspective. i'll look into it and share me experience if something noticeable pops up. thx again

Answer (score 0):

We use Jenkins with the git and docker plugins for this.  Our Dockerfiles are stored in a git repo, with one directory for each Dockerfile and supporting files.  Then in Jenkins we set up the dependencies (manually) and the child images of any parent image are built when the code changes in git.

Comment: but say for example that i want to develop locally, and i have the relationship that i described earlier. if something gets changed in the base image, then i would have to manually build everything and launch the container again, correct?